# Create duplicate records in a query for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table in a Microsoft Access Database:

```
TableName: Cabinets
RoomID - Number
Wall ID - Number
Cabinet ID - Number
Width - Number (double)
Height - Number (double)
Depth - Number (double)
Quantity - Number
```

What I need to do is create a query that will duplicate each row for a number of times specified in the Quantity field.  As an example, let's say that I have the following data:

```
Room ID    Wall ID     Cabinet ID     Width     Height     Depth     Quantity
1          1           1              30        34.5       24        1
1          1           2              42        34.5       24        1
1          1           3              18        34.5       24        2
```

I need to have a query that would create the following:

```
Room ID    Wall ID     Cabinet ID     Width     Height     Depth   
1          1           1              30        34.5       24     
1          1           2              42        34.5       24       
1          1           3              18        34.5       24       
1          1           3              18        34.5       24
```

Now, I have seen, in other questions, that I can create a 'numbers' table to accomplish this, unfortunately, I can't change the table at all.  In fact, I am very limited to what I can actually do with this database.

Here is what I can do:

1. Create a Query that will pull the data
2. Create a Query that will add a 'view' to the database at runtime (before the query to pull the data is run)

Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is incredibly painful in Access, but you can create a numbers table on the fly.  Let's assume that `cabinet_id` is really a unique id in the `cabinets` table.

```
select c.*
from cabinets c left join
     (select (select count(*) from cabinets c2 where c2.cabinet_id <= c.cabinet_id) as n
      from cabinets c
     ) n
     on n.n <= c.quantity;
```

This uses the `cabinets` table to generate a list of numbers, using a correlated subquery to get the numbers.  Note that this assumes that `quantity` is always less than the number of rows in this table.

If you know the ids have no gaps and start at 1, you can simplify this to:

```
select c.*
from cabinets c left join
     (select cabinet_id) as n
      from cabinets c
     ) n
     on n.n <= c.quantity;
```

Comment: Aside from having to change the 'Join' type to a `Left Join` this worked perfectly, thank you so much!